# confused about dynamic-configuration of YI

Tags: haskell, yi-editor

I have install yi-dynamic-configure. The ~/.config/yi/yi.hs is follows:

```
import Yi

main = yi $ defaultVimConfig
```

when i use yi, i get errors:

```
Ambiguous module name ‘Yi’:
it was found in multiple packages: 
yi-0.12.3@yi_588IK8yeps1D4wHHrQVhy4 yi-core-0.14.0@Gh0PE0rnSjz5h4gEVk0B5B
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because I also installed yi-0.12, uninstalling yi-0.12 will solve this problem